# Bulk copy data from line xx to yy in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, sqlbulkcopy

I have a file container all kind of data. Text, headers, comments etc.
I want to be able to bulk copy data from a specific line to a specific line, f.x:

```
This is line 1  
Some Text here  
next line is start of real data  
1,2,3,'test',4  
2,5,4,'ff',5  
5,4,3,'22',1  
previous line was last data line  
Some more text..
```

Is there a way doing this in SQLServer 2008?

Comment: *Have* you tried any of the Bulk import methods? Was there a specific issue with them?

Comment: Yes, I have tried. This works fine when the file contains the data to copy only. Not when the file contains all other kinds of stuff, as in my example.

Comment: *What* have you tried and *what* was the problem? What you want is already supported by all techniques. Checking the docs for both `bcp` and `BULK INSERT` I can see the required parameters are there.  SSIS also has the required functionality and SqlBulkCopy will send whatever you give it - if you give it just 10 rows it will only send 10 rows

Comment: No, Panagiotis, I'm not sure it is supported.   if I do like this(for the example above):   bulk insert BulkTest from 'D:\bulktest.txt'
 WITH (firstrow=4,lastrow=6,FIELDTERMINATOR= ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n') I will not get any data inserted. This only works if the 3 first lines had the same format, as the data lines, i,e, 'This is line 1',1,1,'1',1  etc.

Comment: It seems like the "firstrow" option is not intended for skipping headers etc.